# Sanity.io and Nuxt.js - Cannot find module '@nuxtjs/sanity'

Tags: nuxt.js, sanity

I have created a nuxt.js app in order to connect to sanity.io CMS.
just followed the steps indicated by the docs:

```
yarn create nuxt-app my-app
```

selected a js app with SSR rendering mode and static server

```
cd my-app
yarn dev
```

after this the application is showing the right welcome page of nuxt indicating everything is ok.

then I connect nuxt to sanity.

```
yarn add @nuxtjs/sanity
yarn add @sanity/client
```

adding modules and sanity info to nuxt.config.js, in particular:

```
modules: ["@nuxtjs/sanity"],
  sanity: {
    projectId: "1kszracx",
    dataset: "production"
  },
```

and the application is still working.

when I try to import "greq" to fetch data from sanity i got the issues.
As a test i put the following in "index.vue"

```
<template>
<div>this is a test page</div>
</template>

<script>
import { groq } from "@nuxtjs/sanity";
export default {
  async asyncData({ $sanity }) {
    const query = groq`*[_type == "post"]`;
    const posts = await $sanity.fetch(query);
    return { posts };
  }
};
</script>
```

the error I get:

```
This dependency was not found:                                               friendly-errors 17:49:36
                                                                             friendly-errors 17:49:36
[friendly-errors 17:49:36] * @nuxtjs/sanity in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
                                                                             friendly-errors 17:49:36
To install it, you can run: npm install --save @nuxtjs/sanity                friendly-errors 17:49:36
```

I have installed the @nuxtjs/sanity it is present in my node_modules folder and also is into the package json.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/sanity": "^1.8.3",
    "@sanity/client": "^6.12.4",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

my node version is 21.6.1
I also tried with node v 18.16.1 nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

that's only a mistake in following outdated tutorials.
The latest version of nuxt 3 and sanity.io works with another syntax, very easey and simple.

```
<script setup>
    const query groq`*[(_type == "post")] | order(date desc) {title, slug, date, subtitle, mainImage}`
    const { data } = await useSanityQuery(homeQuery)
</script>
```